# How to plot ROC curve in R given only a linear regression equation

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, roc, auc

I'm trying to plot an ROC curve in R and find the area under it (AUC), given only a regression equation.

Usually, when I have a GLM I would use the command `predict` to do this. For example:

```
library("pROC")
lin_mod <- glm(y ~ p + q, family = "...", data = dat_sd)
prob <- predict(lin_mod, type = c("response"))
```

The coefficients of the model are 0.3 (Intercept), -0.07 (p) and 0.11 (q). To plot the ROC and find the AUC, I use

```
plot(roc(dat_sd$y, prob), print.auc = TRUE)
```

However, when I only have the equation the command doesn't work:

```
library("pROC")    
lin_mod <- 0.3 - 0.07 * dat_sd$p + 0.11 * dat_sd$q
predict(lin_mod, type = c("response"))
```

outputs

`Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

What should I do to successfully plot the curve (and find the area)?

Comment: Try `prob <- 0.3 - 0.07 * dat_sd$p + 0.11 * dat_sd$q;
plot(roc(dat_sd$y, prob), print.auc = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line *is* your predicted response from the data already:

```
lin_mod <- 0.3 - 0.07 * dat_sd$p + 0.11 * dat_sd$q
```

Just pass that response variable to pROC directly:

```
plot(roc(dat_sd$y, lin_mod), print.auc = TRUE)
```